# #pragma warning(push) without #pragma warning(pop)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Using C++ Native solution in Visual Studio 2010.

`#pragma warning (push)` is used in the beginning of the cpp file, after all the includes. After that there are couple of disabled warning by `#pragma warning(disable : XXXX)`.

What are possible consequences of omitting `#pragma warning(pop)` at the end of the file?

Thanks

Comment: The unpopped warning states will start piling up on your computer. and eventually may require you to hire a professional warning state maintainer to clean them out.  Just kidding.  There's no ill effect.  I wonder, though, why you are pushing the warning state at all, though, if you have no intent to pop it back.

Comment: Note however that it will probably confuse future maintainers of the code, who will ask exactly the same question you're asking here.

Comment: I'm actually fixing bugs in existing old code. My concern here is if it affects other (independent) compilation units (cpp files).

Comment: It's like the legend of the king that wanted to award the inventor of chess.  You too underestimate powers of 2.  It only takes 20 copy/pastes to have a million #pragmas.  Compile it and see what happens, now you *know*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any other source files that `#include` that cpp file, then the warning state when compiling the outer file will be messed up -- it could fail to give warnings when the warnings were warranted.

Note, however, that `#include`ing a cpp file is considered bad form and a code smell; there are certain, rare, situations where it might be the right thing to do (such as a build system that `#include`s many source files into one to reduce compilation times, sort of like precompiled headers), but almost always it's the wrong thing to do, even if it manages to compile and link without errors.

If that source file is never `#include`d anywhere else, then failing to have a `#pragma warning(pop)` will not have any adverse consequences, assuming the compiler doesn't complain about that mismatch in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a compiler only setting, it won't have any impact on the program itself. It may though screw up warnings for external includes.

Comment: If you include some external library, for which you also compile the cpp. In my latest project, I use an 3rd party library to compress / uncompress data, and that code uses a #pragma warning guard to avoid warnings during compilation. Its just that if you forget to do the pop, the settings for other files may be wrong, but the application will not have any differences between it activated or not.

Comment: I see what you mean. Its like pushing warnings, changing and not popping inside libraries header which is included in my cpp file. But in my case everything is happening after all the includes.